# Php - empty ArrayObject

Tags: php, arrays, is-empty, arrayobject

The `ArrayObject` class allows objects to work as arrays. When I check if an `ArrayObject` is empty, though, the result is always false

```
echo empty(new ArrayObject()); // returns false
```

Wouldn't it be more coherent with the behavior of an empty array `[]` if it  returned `true`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

PHP's `ArrayObject` isn't interchangeable with arrays. Most array-related functions won't work with it.

The [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) construct only determines whether the given value is [*falsy*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) (while ignoring undefined variable / index errors). An instance of `ArrayObject` evaluates to `true` when it is cast to a boolean.

This would work for both arrays and `ArrayObject`s (since they implement [`Countable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php)):

```
if (!count($variable)) {
    // $variable is an empty array or empty ArrayObject
}
```

Comment: (In my opinion it's a shame that PHP doesn't have more generalised and uniform operator overloading (yes, `empty` is essentially an operator), but... oh, well...)